# Is it right to use two or more different front-end frameworks in a single web app?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web-applications, frameworks, frontend

i'm starting to learn about web development, by now i'm learning some front-end skills, by now i'm trying to use frameworks like Bootstrap, Foundation, Semantic UI, etc... but i've got a question, is it possible to use two frameworks for a single app? if so, is it worth? if not, Why?

Another question about frameworks i have is: Is it good-practice to use a framework to build the front-end of a web app? if not, why? what's the best-practice method to build the front-end?

Comment: " Is it good-practice to use a framework to build the front-end of a web app?" A. Don't ask multiple distinct questions in a single SO post. B. This has been asked before on SO; just search.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, when you commit to a front-end library, you usually impose a look & feel on the application in addition to the framework's coding style. If you try to use two different frameworks (and it is at all possible), you will likely end up with an inconsistent design.

Second of all, it is certainly (often) possible to use more than one framework, as long as they do not interfere with one another. However, there is a finite number of (good) ways to define a front-end framework like Bootstrap or Foundation (using classes), so you will very likely run into some interference. A side note is that mixing frameworks may cause confusion for other developers on the project.

In conclusion: Yes, you will usually find it possible to combine two (or even more) front-end frameworks, but they will likely interfere with another and cause you headaches, and it may lead to an inconsistent design.

My advice as a web developer hobbyist would be to try to commit to only one framework, and add bits and pieces into your code from other frameworks if you need them – but don't try to commit fully to more than one framework.

Comment: Thanks, now, is it bad-practice to use a front-end framework?, is it better to do the front-end without them? Also would like a recommendation about which one to use... i know that some of them are for specific purposes, so, which one would fit for a web app oriented to tests?, any other advice as web-dev?

Comment: Recommendations are largely based on personal opinion and thus off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @cvrebert Ok, where should i ask for recommendations about this?

Comment: @NonExistent I work as a web developer currently for a site that uses no front-end frameworks whatsoever. Also since it's a web application I have to work on the back-end as well. To answer your question: 
- you don't want to " re-invent the wheel ". Mobiles
- 70% of users use mobile technology so responsiveness is a necessity (technically speaking) and you don't want to spend days to weeks fixing and aligning container widths and div-wrapper-margin classes and etc. Frameworks handle that for you ! They are there to make your development process efficient (so less time but maintaining quality)

Comment: @NonExistent But if it is for practice purposes to UNDERSTAND css, js and html works on a skill development level then yes you can subtract frameworks. But if you mean practice purposes towards the INDUSTRY then you will need to be familiar with these frameworks. The (commercial)industry always works with TIME. And if frameworks can reduce development time and still deliver a quality product or service, they will take that any day.