# Is it a good practice to use Material Ui and tailwind in a same project

Tags: material-ui, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using next.js with tailwind css and i somehow need some of the ready to use components in my project so i can save my time, for that i have used material-ui. My application works fine but i have got a warning message. Is is possible to use both technologies **(material-ui and tailwind css)** at same project, if **"yes"**(means if the combination of both wont effect the performance of the project or any other issue in future ) Is there is any way to remove the warning message it am showing you below
[image]

Comment: I would highly recommend not doing this. Pick a singular css framework and/or utility library and stick with it. You'll run into conflicting styles/classes left and right and bloat your project. Learn tailwindcss really well and I'm willing to bet you'll find yourself feeling less and less attracted to ready-made component libraries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it right to use two or more different front-end frameworks in a single web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377686/is-it-right-to-use-two-or-more-different-front-end-frameworks-in-a-single-web-ap)

Comment: @Usama, you can use `classes` object prop in `TextField` props, Tailwind utility will override their classes in Material-UI through use Material-UI API props. so define your styles into `<TextField>` check this Doc https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props

Comment: For the second question: Does this answer your question [React + Material-UI - Warning: Prop className did not match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50685175/11613622)

Comment: Usama, use this link https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app and if you finished to setting, then package install Material-UI. I also using this setting as well.

Comment: This warning message for your nextjs not for using material.

Every time that nextjs make build from your code some css classes create new name.

in this case your formControl was formControl-23 but new one is formControl-1 because that you have this warning it's not an important warning. 

If you want to check it you can run again your nextjs server.

Comment: I have heard that some libraries, like MaterialUI have better baked in accessibility, where AFAIK if you were to style things with tailwind, you wouldn't have the benefits of accessibility. Wonder if anyone has any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 6):

#### Is it good practice ?

> ###### Absolutely Not, *You'll face many naming conflicts and it causes many confusions to the compiler and the precedence will be unusual*

#### But can you achieve this ?

> ###### Yes, you can !!

---

##### To avoid the naming conflicts use the [prefix option](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix) in your `tailwind.config.js` file

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',    Use your desired prefix 
}
```

> So now you can use the prefix `tw-` before the class name of tailwind-css which wont break any of your existing styles.

---

#### Note

If you want tailwind classes to get more precedence than any other css styles , you can set the [important option](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important) to true on `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  important: true,
}
```

---

#### Extra

To understand the css precedence follow this [What is the order of precedence for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

Here is the official documentation: https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#tailwind-css

- Disable preflight in tailwind.config.js
- Add important to your root element
- Use `<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>`